# Finder shows different folder sizes, and number of items

Tags: finder, usb, smb, nas

I am having a strange issue.. I have a Synology server, whose mounts are attached via smb in my Mac. There somewhere I have a folder, which I want to copy paste to another external hard drive, which is connected via usb on my Mac. So basically I made a copy paste, and let the computer finish the work. Copy window was showing 215GB as the total size to paste. By the way the folder contains raw canon camera files with CR2 extension.

So the work was done. I generally check always the folder size and control manually since I do not trust any drive and any computer thing.. I checked the folder size on the USB Disk, which was just copied from the Synology. Macs Get info window shows me **72GB - 2695 items**.

Then I looked to Synology folder again, with the get info. Shows me **215GB - 8001 items**.

Since I also did not get any error from that copy process, I thought sth. should be broken.. I removed the whole folder from the usb drive, started the process again. Again the same thing. 72GB - 2695 items I have now on the usb.

Then I go to Synology folder again, look at the files, and I thoughT "it is impossible that here is 8001 files.." I selected all files with CTRL+A, and made a right click, this time Finder shows me these kind of options "Rename **1200 files**.". I also manually counted the files, actually there are 1200 files.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are there any subfolders? Previewing a folder with SPACE shows the number of children as the number of items. Looking in Get Info shows the total number of *all* descendants as the number of items. For example, I have a "Footage" folder which contains an "EOS_DIGITAL" folder and an "ULTIMA" folder. Preview shows "108.4GB, 2 items", whereas Get Info shows "108.4GB for 771 items", since that is how many individual files exist in that folder tree.

Comment: I checked and there is not any subfolder.. everything is flat.. and space shows me the same. :/

Comment: If you don't mind using the Terminal, consider using [`rsync`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yunfTkvGdT0) for these sorts of large copy operations, since it will show you the progress for each file being copied, and will also check the file contents, so as to only copy data which needs to be copied.

Comment: Also, I would check with `du -sh` how much space is actually consumed in the source and target folders. Annoyingly, Finder does not have an option to only copy files which don't yet exist on the target.

Comment: The Finder's **Get Info** window doesn't count invisible files such as `.DS_Store` and dot files for the total items, although the total size should be the same.